# JAVA Looping a formula

Tags: java, loops, formula

To start, I'm a relatively new programmer as it pertains to JAVA. I've searched for many things but it's possible I'm not search for the right thing. I'm basically trying to list from the first "year" to the 10th "year" a starting amount, multiplied by the percentage, and added to the starting amount. Then, I want to take that new amount and do the same thing over and over again until it gets to 10. Or, even a specified total ex:2000.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double startAmount = 1000;
    double ratePercentage = 0.05;
    double newAmount;


    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        newAmount = startAmount + (startAmount * ratePercentage);
        System.out.println(i + " " + newAmount);

    }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a second to review the following link to get a good idea on how to ask questions that will have the best chance of getting a great answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achive. But assuming you are trying to do some sort of compounding interest. This should help.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double startAmount = 1000;
    double ratePercentage = 0.05;
    double newAmount;

    newAmount = startAmount;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        newAmount = newAmount + (newAmount * ratePercentage);
        System.out.println(i + " " + newAmount);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
double startAmount = 1000;
double ratePercentage = 0.05;
double newAmount;


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    newAmount = startAmount + (startAmount * ratePercentage);
    System.out.println(i + " " + newAmount);
    startAmount=newAmount;

}

}
```